# Replace characters from a string SHELL

Tags: string, shell, unix, replace, character

Here is my problem :

I created a script that refers all files in my dir X  with the "find ." command and I
stock them in a file , one file per line like that  :

```
./dossier1/dossier2/fic.txt
./dossier1/dossier2/fic.jpg
```

I 'd like to replace with :

```
filename;/opt/InfoVista/Portal/site/rubrics/help/dossier1/dosssier2/;no;555;
```

Here is what i tried:

```
find . >> list_fic.txt


ligne=';no;555'
std=/opt/InfoVista/Portal/site/rubrics/help/


while read line  
do 
        filename=${$line##\.*\/} // allow me to delete the path and keep just the filenam
    final=$std$nomfic$ligne
        echo  $final >> final.txt // put the line in the final.txt file
done < list_fic.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to create a file containing -for each files contained in the current directory-the following structure :

thenameofthefileOrdir;the/absolute/path;no;555;

I modified your solution , that works fine !!!

```
#!/bin/bash

find . | nawk -F/ -v dir="/opt/InfoVista/Portal/site/rubrics/help/" -v l=";no;555" '
{ 
OFS="/" ; f=$NF; NF--; sub(/^\.\//,"") ; OFS=";" ; print f,dir $0 l
}' >> final.txt
```

Now , i have the first line of my final.txt that contains the current dir , and the two last lines are corresponding to this script and final.txt , 
These 3 lines are useless (the first one , and the two lasts.

Can i exclude them ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do it in awk:

```
awk -F/ -v dir="/opt/InfoVista/Portal/site/rubrics/help/" -v l=";no;555;" '
{ 
    OFS="/" ; f=$NF; NF--; sub(/^\.\//,"") ; OFS=";" ; print f,dir $0 l
}' list_fic.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. But if the suffix and prefix are fixed, here is one way to do it

```
 find . | awk -F "./" '{print "Filname;/opt/InfoVista/Portal/site/rubrics/help/"$1$2<any num of fields>";no;555"}' > final.txt
```